# Given $A^2$, find all $A$ that satisfy

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the set of all matrices $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ satisfying $A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$

I have been given this problem. Do I just need to take $A=\begin{pmatrix} a &b& c \\ d& e& f \\ g& h& i \end{pmatrix}$ and solve for the variables? or is there a better way

Comment: You could consider the problem geometrically, as linear maps $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$. It should, at least, give you some ideas.

Comment: There are many ways to approach this problem. $\bf A$ is for example *nilpotent*, since ${\bf A}^4 = {\bf 0}$. This puts constraints on eigenvalues of $\bf A$ which in turn puts constraints on the characteristic polynomial which the matrix must fulfill according to the Caley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: Adding onto mathreadler's comment, because $A^4=0$ but $A^2\neq 0$, and because every matrix is similar to a matrix in Jordan Normal Form, you can find $A$ up to conjugation without a lot of computation.  However, there is a bit of work to find all possible $A$ (instead of just one $A$) from this point.

Answer (score 5):

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a &b& c \\ d& e& f \\ g& h& i \end{pmatrix}$$ as OP suggests. Now clearly, 
$$A^4=0$$ and thus the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^4$. However the minimal polynomial has degree $\leq 3$ and therefore the minimal polynomial divides $x^3$. Thus we have 
$$A^3=0$$ and so
$$\begin{pmatrix} a &b& c \\ d& e& f \\ g& h& i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}=0$$
And $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0\\0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a &b& c \\ d& e& f \\ g& h& i \end{pmatrix}
=0$$. Which imply that

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &b& c \\ 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& h& i \end{pmatrix}$$
 The original equation now becomes much easier to solve we get
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &b& c \\ 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& c^{-1}& 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: +1, this is much nicer than the approach I would have taken (which i was writing up, but now don't think I will finish).

Comment: @Aaron Sorry about that, you can still post, there may be good ideas in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to square a generic matrix and solve the resulting system of 9 quadratic equations in 9 variables, the task appears (to me, at least) quite daunting.  However, we can simplify the task significantly by first solving the problem up to conjugation using [JNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

The first task is to use the information we have to deduce the minimal and characteristic polynomials of $A$.  Given the value of $A^2$, we know that $A^4=0$.  Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is a polynomial of degree at most $3$ which divides $x^4$, so is one of $x$, $x^2$, or $x^3$.  Since $A^2$ is nonzero, the minimal polynomial must be $m_A(x)=x^3$. Since the characteristic polynomial is of degree $3$ and is divisible by the minimal polynomial (and has the same roots, only with potentially larger multiplicities, a fact we do not need), we have that the characteristic polynomial is $p_A(x)=x^3$.

The minimal and characteristic polynomials of a matrix do not always determine a matrix up to conjugation (although in this case, they do).  In terms of the Jordan blocks, if $m_M(x)$ has $(x-a)$ as a factor with multiplicity $i$ and $p_M(x)$ has $(x-a)$ as a factor with multiplicity $j$, then the largest block of eigenvalue $a$ will have size $i$, and the sum of the sizes of the blocks with eigenvalue $a$ will be $j$.

In our particular case, all our blocks must have eigenvalue $0$, and we must have a block of size $3$, which (because we are a $3\times 3$ matrix) must be all of $A$ (up to conjugation).  Therefore, we have the following:

There exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that

$$ A = P  \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1 \\ 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix} P^{-1}; \qquad A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}= P  \begin{pmatrix} 0 &0& 1 \\ 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix} P^{-1}.$$

At this point, one can solve for $P$ as in the solution by Rene, and then solve for $A$.